# How to require propertyA OR propertyB in a GraphQL Schema

Tags: graphql

In the type definition below, is there a way to require name or model, instead of name and model?

```
type Starship {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  model: String!
  length(unit: LengthUnit = METER): Float
}
```

I may have name or model due to some legacy data limitations.  I would rather enforce this at the GraphQL validation layer, rather than in code.

EDIT:
There is some good discussion about adding validation to the graphQL spec, which you can read here: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/361

There are also a couple of libraries to extend validation:

https://github.com/xpepermint/graphql-type-factory

https://github.com/stephenhandley/graphql-validated-types

I'm going to stick with validating the types in code, at least until they add better support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Type-System.Non-Null):

> By default, all types in GraphQL are nullable; the null value is a valid response for all of the above types. To declare a type that disallows null, the GraphQL Non‐Null type can be used. This type wraps an underlying type, and this type acts identically to that wrapped type, with the exception that null is not a valid response for the wrapping type. A trailing exclamation mark is used to denote a field that uses a Non‐Null type like this: `name: String!`.

An individual field may be nullable or non-nullable. Non-null validation happens at the field level, independent of other fields. So there is no mechanism for validating whether some combination of fields are or are not null.

Comment: yep, out of the box it doesn't appear to be possible.  There is some good discussion on adding validation to the graphql spec though.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use `union` to represent name or model concept . As `union` only works with object type now , that means you have also model name and model as object type first.

Code wise the schema looks like :

```graphql
type Name {
  value : String!
}

type Model {
  value : String!
}

union NameOrModel = Name | Model

type Starship {
  id: ID!
  nameOrModel : NameOrModel!
  length(unit: LengthUnit = METER): Float
}
```

It is very ugly IMO as it introduces many unnecessary noise and complexity to the schema .So I would prefer to stick with your original schema and do that check manually in the backend.

Comment: I was thinking a union would work, but would be too smelly.  I figured i'd ask and see if anyone had a simple solution I wasn't aware of

Comment: This also unfortunately wouldn't work for input objects, although @Kevin 's question pertained specifically to validating responses. As a workaround, you could also use a custom scalar to represent all sort of custom validation behavior, but then that validation logic would not be visible through introspection.

Comment: Yes . It is sad. Hope GraphQL will allow  InputObject to be used with union [soon](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/488) :D